# Sum of the external elements - matrix to function C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, matrix, sum

I need to create a program that computes the external elements of a matrix. The matrix should be set by the user.
My idea is to create a first part of the program where the user can write the elements of the matrix, after that this matrix is given to a function that sets the internal elements to 0 and than gives it back to the main() and then launch another function that computes the sum of all elements. 
The problem is that I am not able to pass to the function the matrix that's declared in the main {}. 
I am almost sure that I need to use pointers, however I have no idea how to use them in this situation... Could you please help? 
That's the code I have written so far:

```
 #include <iostream>
#define MAX 10
using namespace std;
int zeroMatrix (int mat [][10], int, int);
int main()
{   //ask the user the number of rows and columns of the matrix.
    int rows,cols;
    cout << "please insert the number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "insert the number of columns: ";
    cin >> cols;
    //accepting values
    int matrix [rows] [cols];
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        {
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++)
            {
                cout <<"insert the element A(" << i <<","<< j << ") of the matrix " ;
                cin >> matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    zeroMatrix (matrix [rows][cols]);
}

//change the previous matrix into a new matrix with the internal elements = 0

 int zeroMatrix (int mat [][10], int rows, int cols )
 {
    for (int i=1; i<rows-1; i++)
        { for (int j=1; j<cols-1 ; j++)
            {
                mat[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: One definitive problem, and one possible problem: C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use `std::vector` instead for portability. And in the `zeroMatrix` why do the loop starts with index `1` and end at one less than the size?

Comment: By the way, what are you asking about? The build error you should get for calling `zeroMatrix` wrongly? Something else?

Comment: it starts from 1 becouse it has to change the internal elements of the matrix. so starting from 1 and ending to rows -1 it changes only the internal. correct? 
anyway i am asking to correcting this code using pointers. I am not able to pass the matrix in the main to the function.

Comment: @LuigiRusso Don't use raw arrays and raw pointers in c++. Rather go with `std::vector` as advised, or create your own `Matrix` class to make your life easier.

Comment: @user0042 thank you for you advice, I have no idea what 's std::vector. Could you send me a link to understand it better and some example on how to use it? would we very grateful thank you

Comment: @LuigiRusso [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) you go.

Comment: it seems to me that for using std::vector I must use a library called <vector>, problem is my professor want me to use only the standard <iostream> and std. 
however I have taken a glance. Very useful.

Comment: int matrix[row][column] is not standard c++. declare int **matrix; then allocate memory matrix = new int*[row]; after that                                                    
for(int i=0;i<row;++i)                
   matrix[i]=new int[col];  After that you can  set elements just like with two dim arrays like matrix[0][4] =7;

Comment: @JPX - Would you like to write down the entire code? I have tried and receive a lot of errors, probably becouse I don't understand why using new int and the int ** matrix. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    void zeroMatrix (int **mat, int, int);//makes the inner elements zero

    int sumExternals(int **mat, int rows, int cols);//sums the external elements without
                                               //using  zeroMatrix

    void printMatrix(int **mat, int, int);//prints a matrix on the console window

    int main()
    {   //ask the user the number of rows and columns of the matrix.
        int rows,cols;
        cout << "please insert the number of rows: ";
        cin >> rows;
        cout << "insert the number of columns: ";
        cin >> cols;
        //accepting values

        int **matrix = new int*[rows];

        for(int i=0; i<rows; ++i)
           matrix[i] = new int[cols];

        for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
            {
            for (int j=0; j<cols; j++)
                {
                    cout <<"insert the element A(" << i <<","<< j << ") of the matrix " ;
                    cin >> matrix[i][j];
                }
            }

        printMatrix(matrix,rows,cols);          //print the matrix
        cout<<sumExternals(matrix,rows,cols)<<endl;  //get the sum of the external elements

        //Just so you can see how to proper call the function zeroMatrix
        zeroMatrix(matrix,rows,cols);
        printMatrix(matrix,rows,cols);
    }

    //changes the previous matrix into a new matrix with the internal elements = 0
    void zeroMatrix (int **mat, int rows, int cols )
     {
        for (int i=1; i<rows-1; i++)
             for (int j=1; j<cols-1; j++)
                mat[i][j] = 0;


     }

    //calculates the sum of the external elements of a matrix
    int sumExternals(int **mat, int rows, int cols)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<cols;++j)
        {
            sum+=mat[0][j];         // adds the upper bound elements to sum
            sum+=mat[rows-1][j];    // adds the lower bound elements to sum
        }

        //Take caution not to add elements which are already taken into account
        for(int i=1;i<rows-1;++i)
        {
            sum+=mat[i][0];         //adds the left bound elements to sum
            sum+=mat[i][cols-1];    //adds the right bound elements to sum

        }

        return sum;
    }

    void printMatrix(int **matrix, int rows, int cols)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<rows;++i)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<cols;++j)
                cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" ";

            cout<<endl;
        }
   }
```

I added the function sumExternals which calculates the sum of the external matrix elements but without using your zeroMatrix function.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)** instead of array. Also, there's no need for two separate functions. One to find the sum of external elements and other to set internal elements to 0. You can achieve both tasks in the same function. Refer function **external_elements_sum** written below.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <vector>
using namespace std;

int external_elements_sum(vector<vector<int> >&arr)    // function that finds sum of external elements and set internal elements to 0
{
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0; arr.size()>0 && i<arr[i].size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr[i].size();j++)
        {
            if(i==0 || i==arr.size()-1 || j==0 || j==arr[i].size()-1)  // external elements
                sum+=arr[i][j];
            else arr[i][j]=0;     // internal elements
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    vector< vector<int> >arr;
    int i,j,number,rows=3,cols=4;
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        vector<int>v;
        for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            cin>>number;
            v.push_back(number);
        }
        arr.push_back(v);
    }
    int sum = external_elements_sum(arr);
    for(i=0;i<arr.size()>0 && arr[0].size();i++)   // arr.size()>0 to check corner case like if row is 0
    {
        for(j=0;j<arr[i].size();j++)
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Sum of externale elements is: "<<sum;
    return 0;
}

Input:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
2 5 1 4

Output:
1 2 3 4 
5 0 0 8 
2 5 1 4 
Sum of externale elements is: 35
```